# Setting a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem where I am try to set the following variable

```
set params=--no_data=true --add-drop-table=false --skip-dump-date
```

However I keep getting the error **'--no_data' is not recognized as an internal or external command**.  How do I get round this?

Comment: Try it with \`\``"quotes"`''

Comment: I have tried that but no luck

Comment: It works fine from a command prompt. Please [edit] your question to show your actual code in context instead of a single line. (As a side question: you have a strange mix of underscores (`no_data`) and hyphens (`add-drop-table`). Are you sure parameters to the same executable are so different in format?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with that line but with another line that attempts to invoke 'params' as an executable. Probably that other line should first list the executable (mysqldump.exe presumably) and then pass in params, something like this:

```
mysqldump.exe %params%
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
set "params=--no_data=true --add-drop-table=false --skip-dump-date"
```